# How to format an SQL result?

Tags: node.js

so i'm new to SQL (And programming in general) and i'm building something that require a SQL select.
The selection works fine, if a certain value exists on the DB, it returns me this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, token: 'cuf0njqu4qmur5docha5ka', used: 0 } ]
```

If it doesn't exist, it gives me this:

```
[]
```

But i'm using Node JS and I can't get it to compare [ ] with null, is there any way I can set this empty array as 0 or false?

The code:

```
const sql = `SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = '${token}' AND used = 0`

    pool.query(sql, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
        const valid = data
        console.log(data)

        if (valid !== null) {
            const used = `UPDATE tokens SET used = 1 WHERE token = '${token}'`
            pool.query(used, function(err, data) {
                console.log("The token is valid!")
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log("The token is not valid.")
        }
    })
```

Comment: The token being null or not, it returns me "The token is valid" always.

Comment: Null (data in column does not exist) and empty resultset (there are no rows) are two different things! No result is not null in sql either, you need an outer join or a subquery to get null values if no matching row is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like data is an empty array `[]` which is still a 'truthy' value.

you can see truthyness of an expression using !! (not not)

```
console.log(!![]) 
> true

console.log(!!0)
> false
```

you can check the length property of an array.

```
const valid = data && data.length;
```

or

```
const valid = !!data.length
```

Comment: It worked, thank you